# Multiple executable accessing the same folder at the same time

Tags: c#, python, os.walk

We have a python application that checks a directory(C:\sample\folder) every 5 seconds, there's also this external application(.net app) that puts file into that same directory (C:\sample\folder).

Will there be any conflict when the two application access the same folder at the same time (accidentally)?

Conflicts like :

- the external app wont be able to place a file because the python app is currently walking through that same directory?

Comment: should be no problem unless both access the same file. so you should take good care of handling I/O-Exceptions properly and think of some kind of wait&retry-behaviour

Comment: No. The only conflict could be, the external app starts writing a file to the directory and python app checks the directory and realizes the new file, and tries to access the new file before it is fully written

Comment: The external app is just copy pasting the file to the directory. No writing involve. Thank you for confirming @MarcoForberg and Oguz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine for the external app to create and write to a file. If the Python app is *reading* a file, the .NET app may not be able to write to it while Python is reading it, without both processes opening the file in a shareable way, however.

Likewise if the Python app is going to start reading the newly-created file, it may either find that it can't do so until the .NET app has finished writing to it, or it may read incomplete data. Again, changes would quite possibly be required to both processes to allow reading at all.

It's worth thoroughly testing all the poosibilities you're concerned about, possibly involving the creation of a "fake" external app which writes to a file very slowly, but opening it in the same way that the real one does.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Skeet. The external is just copy pasting a file to the same directory, no writing involve. Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: @anon: If it's copying a file, that *is* writing to it. Files don't exist without being written :) Now if it were a "move" operation within the same file system, that *might* be atomic, in which case you wouldn't need to worry... but copies aren't.

Comment: Oh I see @Jon Skeet, so it means that when the external app is copy pasting the file to the directory and the python sees it, is it possible that they try to access it at the same time? Of course python wont be able to open it right?

Comment: @anon: That depends on how the C# code is copying it, and on how the Python code is accessing it. (It's odd to talk about an application "copy pasting" - it would normally either be a call to a Copy method, or explicitly opening a file and writing to it. It seems unlikely that it would be a clipboard operation. Do you have the source to the C# application?)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the source for the c# application, i only have the python one. @Jon Skeet, the workflow of the python is it uses the os.walk and when it finds a file it opens it reads the file.

Comment: @anon: Okay, that makes it harder to say for sure. You should at least handle the possibility that a file may exist that you can't read yet. Ideally, try to work out a way of testing this - but really you need to know how the C# app is opening the file handle :(

Comment: Thank you @Jon Skeet, atleast i know where to go from here. Will try to simulate different situation of handling the file. Thanks alot!